# What’s the meaning of “off” in “better off”?

Tags: meaning

According to [Collins Dictionary](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.collinsdictionary.com/it/amp/inglese/be-better-off)

> If you say that someone would be better off doing something, you are advising them to do it or expressing the opinion that it would benefit them to do it, as in:
>
> - *If you've got bags, you're better off taking a taxi.*
> - *Their stance seems to be that a baby or child is better off in its country of birth.*

What’s the meaning and function of the preposition “off” used after better. Wouldn’t “better” alone suffice in this case?

Answer (score 1):

From the Oxford English Dictionary: [behind a paywall]

A. adv.

Used predicatively: in a more favourable or advantageous position; esp. better provided with money or other resources. Cf. well off adv.

Also:

Frequency (in current use):
Origin: **Formed within English, by conversion.** Etymon: of prep.

And finally from that entry, also relevant here:

A. adv.
 I. General uses.
Off has been used since the Middle English period with many verbs, e.g. buy v., come v., dash v.1, get v., go v., look v., mark v., palm v., pass v., rattle v.1, show v., take v., etc.: see the first element. In most of these the basic uses of off correspond to those given below, while (as with other phrasal verbs) the further developments take a more idiomatic turn.

*** x****

I am assuming (and I could be wrong) that since it was formed from the preposition ***of***, the original usage might have been some kind of comparative: the better of two things. And eventually came to have a meaning on its own: better off, worse off, well off.

Please note: to **be better off** is not the idiom: You **had better** [verb].

Answer (score 0):

**Better off** is an idiom, essentially stemming from **well off**.  To be **well off** is to be wealthy or prosperous.

Concentrating on *prosperity*, rather than *wealth*: [**to prosper**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/prosper) means *"to be or become successful, especially financially"*.  The idiom, **better off**, therefore most-directly means *"more likely to be successful"*.

**Better** on it's own would not be correct, in either sentence:

- *"If you've got bags, you're **better** taking a taxi"* (is not grammatic or, at least, is not natural)
- *"Their stance seems to be that a baby or child is **better** in its country of birth."* (alludes more it being a better situation for *them*, not necessarily better for *the child*)

Without substantially changing the meaning, for the first sentence, you could try:

- *"If you've got bags, you [had|'d] better take a taxi"*
- *"If you've got bags, your best [option|bet] is [taking] a taxi"*

If I had to change the second sentence, I would probably rework it completely.  In doing so, it would no longer be as succinct.

Comment: "If you've got bags, you're better taking a taxi" - pretty natural and normal in British English.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: not to *this* British Englishman but, like I often imply here, we'll all tolerate minor mistakes when they don't affect the overall understanding...

Comment: Some of us have different notions of what constitutes a "mistake".

Comment: If you've got bags, you'd better take a taxi.